# Split Database results by month

Tags: c#, database

I am trying to return 6 numbers from a database one number for each month.

Currently I am using two dates 6 months apart to interrogate the database and return a sum number, I would like to return 6 numbers representing each month between the two

my code so far is;

```
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("SELECT sum([sum]) FROM Attendance WHERE ([Attendance_Date]) >= ? AND ([Attendance_Date]) <= ? AND [Person] = ?", Program.DB_CONNECTION);
        com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", fromDate));
        com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", toDate));
        com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", person.ID));

        OleDbDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                int attendance = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetDouble(0));
                MessageBox.Show(attendance.ToString());
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
        dr.Close();
```

does anyone know how I can repeat the above for 6 different sets of dates determined by the fromdate and the todate?

Answer (score 0):

You can seperate the date into its parts and focus on the month part.

You can use the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(MONTH, [Attendance_Date]) AS Month,
    SUM(Value) AS Sum
FROM
    Attendance
WHERE
    [Person] = @personId
    AND [Attendance_Date] >= @fromDate
    AND [Attendance_Date] < @toDate
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(MONTH, [Attendance_Date])
```

Please bear in mind that this query will return more than one resulot with two columns, so you must use a DataReader to read distinct rows. Your resultset will be somehow like this:

```
Month       Value
  4          250
  5          180
  7          200
  8          300
  9           25
```

P.S. : This example covers a 6 month period of dates between 01 April and 1 October. And also month June does not have any records. And also bear in mind that this code is spesifically written with T-SQL targetting Microsoft SQL. ON other variants (Oracle, mySQL query might vary due to SQL differences)

Comment: I would just suggest clarification that if other language, the syntax for getting the month may be different, such as MONTH( someDateField ), and offer examples and clarification of that database source.  The person posting should in the future identify which database they are working with anyhow.

Comment: Thank you very much for the warning. I didn't notice, but the user did not added ms-sql or t-sql as label, so this information is quite useful for future reference. Thank you very much for reminding me.